# Junit5 call methos with parameter but receive error: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter

Tags: junit5

I should perform a Junit5 test where method 'test1' can receive a String parameter

I need recall again this method from a new @Test case called 'call_test1WithParameter' passing the parameter.

It is possible to do that in Junit5?
Moreover, when I run method "test1", I receive this error:
There is a way do perform this test case as by me indicated?
Thanks in advance

org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException:
No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [java.lang.String arg1] in method [void com.netsgroup.igfs.cg.test.IntegrationTest.MyTest.test1(org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo,java.lang.String)].
Thanks in advance for your support on This.
Bolow my test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


class MyTest {
    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTest.class);
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void test1(TestInfo testInfo, String myOrderId){

        log.info("Start test case: " + testInfo.getDisplayName());
        
        if (myOrderId!=null)
            log.info("MyOrderId is: " + myOrderId);
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void call_test1WithParameter(TestInfo testInfo){
        log.info("Start test case: " + testInfo.getDisplayName());
        test1(testInfo, "OrderId_123456");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need parameters? Who will provide values? Ordinarily you need to use some JUnit annotation to answer the second question for JUnit. AFAIK you cant just have parameterized test without parameter source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you specify some arguments in your test method and you need to configure it in order to tell JUnit how to resolve the value for those parameters.

For the arguments that are provided by JUnit such as `TestInfo` , `TestReport` or `RepetitionInfo` , it will be automatically be resolved without any extra configuration.

But for other arguments such as the orderId in your case ,you have to change your test case to a [`@ParameterizedTest`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) such that you can use `@ValueSource`/ `@EnumSource` / `@MethodSource` /  `@CsvSource` or  `@ArgumentsSource` etc. to define the actual value for the orderId (see [this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources) for details).

So change your test case to the following should solve your problem :

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"order1" , "order2" , "order3"}) 
@Order(1)
void test1(String myOrderId , TestInfo testInfo) {

        log.info("Start test case: " + testInfo.getDisplayName());

        if (myOrderId != null)
            log.info("MyOrderId is: " + myOrderId);
}
```

One thing that need to pay attention is that the arguments that are resolved by argument sources (i.e `@ValueSource`) should be come first in the argument list. (see [this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-lifecycle-interop)).

Comment: I need also  need reuse again the  method "test1" in another @Test case like this:

Comment: I also need recall method "test1" using method "test2"
When I call in the first time the method "test1" I can set a 'dummy' value in order to process the test case correctly with a dummy parameter.
Do you know if there is another way to manage te @Test case on method "test1" without setting a dummy ValueSource?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad to hear. So please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.